# Generating Function (Discrete Maths)

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, generating-functions, differential

$$
t_{n}=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}{0} & {\text { if } n<1} \\ {n-1+\frac{1}{n^{2}} \sum_{k=1}^{n}\left[(k-1) t_{k-1}+(n-k) t_{n-k}\right]} & {\text { otherwise }}\end{array}\right.
$$

> Let $T(z)$ be a generating function for $t_n$:
>   $$
> T(z) = t_0 + t_1 z + t_2 z^2 +\ldots + t_n z^n + \ldots
> $$
>   Show that
>   $$
> T''(z) = \frac{3z-1}{z(1-z)} T'(z) + \frac{2z+4}{(1-z)^4}
> $$

Can anyone share thoughts on solving this question?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: To sove this question, we need more informations concerning the sequence $(t_n)$.

Comment: This is false unless $t_1 = 0$. Since $$\frac{3z - 1}{z(1 - z)} = -\frac{1}{z} + \sum_{n = 0}^\infty 2z^n$$ and when we multiply by $T'(z)$ the coefficient of $1/z$ on the right side will be $-t_1$, while left hand side, of course, has no $1/z$ in it..

Comment: I forgot to add the sequence $t_n$. Please refer to the updated post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice (and remember) that

$$\frac{3z - 1}{z(1 - z)} = -\frac{1}{z} + \sum_{n = 0}^\infty2z^n$$

and

$$\frac{2z + 4}{(1 - z)^4} = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty(n + 1)(n + 2)^2 z^n$$

using geometric series and [binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series).

Now we can rewrite the one we wanted to show as $$\sum_{n = 0}^\infty (n +2)(n+1)t_{n +2} z^n = \left(-\frac{1}{z} + \sum_{n = 0}^\infty2z^n\right)\sum_{n = 0}^\infty (n + 1)t_{n + 1}z^n + \sum_{n = 0}^\infty (n + 1)(n + 2)^2 z^n.$$

We now compare the coefficient of $z^n$ on both sides.

For $n \geq 0$ the cofficient of $z^n$ in the first term on the right hand side is $$-(n + 2)t_{n +2}  + \sum_{k = 0}^n 2(n - k + 1)t_{n - k + 1}$$
(To get $z^n$, we multiply $z^k$ in the $-1/z +\sum_{n = 0}^\infty$ and $z^{n - k}$ in $T'(z)$ )

Thus, the cofficient of $z^n$ on the right hand side is $$ -(n + 2)t_{n +2} + \sum_{k = 0}^n 2(n - k + 1)t_{n - k +1} + (n + 1)(n + 2)^2$$
and on the left hand side is $(n + 1)(n + 2)t_{n + 2}$.

simplifying  we got $$(n + 2)^2t_{n + 2} = (n + 1)(n + 2)^2 + \sum_{k = 0}^n 2(n - k+1)t_{n - k+1}.$$

Can you continue from here?

The only thing you need to show is $$\sum_{k = 0}^n 2(n + 1 - k)t_{n + 1 - k} = \sum_{k = 1}^{n + 2} [(k - 1)t_{k - 1} + (n + 2 - k)t_{n + 2 - k}]$$

**Hint:** Try tho change the index of summation on the left hand side and use the fact that $2x = x + x$.

Comment: Thanks for the narrow downing the problem in such detail.

$$
-(n+2) t_{n+2}+\sum_{k=0}^{n} 2(n-k+1) t_{n-k+1}
$$

Can you help me with the steps you performed to obtain the coefficient of z^n from R.H.S.?

Comment: @John Peter Sure. When we multiply $$\left(-\frac{1}{z} + \sum_{n = 0}^\infty2z^n\right)\sum_{n = 0}^\infty (n + 1)t_{n + 1}z^n$$ to get $z^n$ we first multiply $- \frac{1}{z}$ and $(n + 2)t_{n +2}z^{n + 1}$  then

\begin{align*} 2 &&\text{with}&&(n+1)t_{n+1} z^n \\ 
2z && \text{with} && nt_n z^{n - 1} \\   
\vdots \\
2z^n &&\text{with} && t_1
\end{align*}
then sum them all.